# html/css/js - marquee, scroll one element then pause, then scroll again

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, marquee

I am trying to create an overlay page for my twitch channel. I play Rocket League and the tracker network site provides overlays that show your rank.

Basically what I have put together is a marquee with a bunch of iframes to grab the rank overlays and scroll them. It works pretty well so far.

What I'd like to do is have it pause on load, scroll slowly to the next one, then pause again, and repeat at the end. I'm having a bit of trouble with finding the right combination of words to search in Google about this, most queries I get answers relating to scroll-stop with javascript.

Here's the current code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        iframe {
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<marquee>
    <iframe src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/347710c7-d003-47ec-8c56-29269060692c"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/687c5759-99f1-4f40-95c3-377cfb1751be"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/b8efb59c-02ae-4edf-9c9d-50a6d1643064"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/80fc2dab-f197-452e-827d-36aafdeca87d"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/76576b68-97aa-42a5-a5e4-45574ab0d3e9"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/fe174a33-4b60-4bcd-aed6-3188dbf1d432"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/7c1a3a59-7540-4c15-a5b4-24d19dbd5880"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/ebc95461-8851-4576-a8bf-0f8aec7c9d46"></iframe>
</marquee>
</body>
</html>
```

Any tips would be appreciated! Also looking into making it pure css/html without iframes and marquee in the future.

Comment: Do you think maybe you could use `setTimeout` and `scrollIntoView`?

Comment: I'll take a look at those, thanks for mentioning them!

Answer (score 1):

Got this working how I wanted :)
Used pure CSS animations. Had to do some math to figure out how long the total animation would be, then figure out the percentages of the keyframes.
Thanks to @The_Paradox for pointing me to some JavaScript methods that put me in a rabbit-hole to find the CSS animation things!
(I am still using iframes, but tbf it's not a bad way to go for this type of thing...)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @keyframes mq1 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            1%  { transform:translateX(0);      }
            9%  { transform:translateX(0);      }
            10%  { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq2 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            10% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            11% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            19% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            20% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }

        }

        @keyframes mq3 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            20% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            21% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            29% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            30% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq4 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            30% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            31% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            39% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            40% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq5 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            40% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            41% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            49% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            50% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq6 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            50% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            51% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            59% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            60% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq7 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            60% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            61% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            69% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            70% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq8 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            70% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            71% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            79% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            80% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq9 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            80% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            81% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            89% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            90% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq10 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            90% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            91% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            99% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }
        .marquee {
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
            margin: 10px auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            white-space: nowrap;
            vertical-align: text-top;
            border: 0px;
        }

        .marquee iframe {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: center;
            transform:translateX(100%);
        }

        iframe.marquee:nth-child(1) {
            animation: mq1 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(2) {
            animation: mq2 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(3) {
            animation: mq3 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(4) {
            animation: mq4 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(5) {
            animation: mq5 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(6) {
            animation: mq6 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(7) {
            animation: mq7 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(8) {
            animation: mq8 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(9) {
            animation: mq9 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(10) {
            animation: mq10 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }

/*
        .marquee.iframe:nth-child(1) {
            animation: left-one 20s ease infinite;
        }
        .marquee.iframe:nth-child(2) {
            animation: left-two 20s ease infinite;
        }
*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="marquee">
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/347710c7-d003-47ec-8c56-29269060692c"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/687c5759-99f1-4f40-95c3-377cfb1751be"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/b8efb59c-02ae-4edf-9c9d-50a6d1643064"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/80fc2dab-f197-452e-827d-36aafdeca87d"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/76576b68-97aa-42a5-a5e4-45574ab0d3e9"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/fe174a33-4b60-4bcd-aed6-3188dbf1d432"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/7c1a3a59-7540-4c15-a5b4-24d19dbd5880"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/ebc95461-8851-4576-a8bf-0f8aec7c9d46"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src=""></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src=""></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A note about the keyframes for anyone working with them - you need to have the starting (0%) and ending (100%) set to what you want it to be doing, then the start time and end time in between with their same transforms, then whatever animation in between them.